# Galaxy Emulator for x86

Tags: android

I have wrote several apps and tested all of them on my xperia Z and android emulator succesfully.

But I have a lot of complaints from Galaxy series owner (S3, S2, Note 1 & 2) that the app have problems.

I wonder if there is any way to run galaxy rom on emulator? I've read that it's possible but I don't know where to download the rom and required files and how to set it up? I want the whole system image, not the skin only!

Or maybe I buy one of them, in this case I prefer to buy note 2. Are their rom compatible so if my app work on note 2 then works on S3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ROM specific crash is usually local to the device and its hardware, and running the ROM on an emulator wouldn't help. In anycase, you cannot run device ROMs on emulators. The closest the emulator can duplicate a device is by copying the screen dimensions and density and some hardware features like RAM etc.

You cannot run a device ROM on an emulator because the device ROM only contains the drivers for a very specific set of hardware, which the emulator will not support.

There is no guarantee that if your app runs on the Note 2 it will run on the S3. If your app crashes due to a ROM bug, the two devices will most probably not share it, as their ROMs are developed individually.

You can either buy the devices it is crashing on, or try posting the LogCat trace you get from the crash here along with related code in a new question.

Comment: So maybe the best option is to buy and S3 as it's the most common android device?

Comment: @Ali I can't comment on the best option. I would personally try to post the logcat and code on sites like SO that offer help and see if anyone has encountered the problem before. You might even know a friend or two who has a device you can borrow for a day. If neither of those work out, you may have to buy a device.

Comment: Thank you, So I think it's better to try and collect the logcats from those users.

Comment: @Ali Yeah, it would be better to begin with. If they downloaded your app from Google Play, they can simply click send when the crash dialog comes up to send you the logcat. If not, you can add [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) to your app and have them install that update, which will automatically send you crash reports.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [Samsung Remote Test Lab](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action#), which allows remote testing on real devices (service availability depends on your location, though).

Besides, while buying a real device for testing such as Note 2 is useful, it won't grant you that you won't still get issues on the other devices.